# How to select the immediate rows of a table using CSS

Tags: html, css

In CSS, we can specify this style against the immediate child rows of a table:

```
table > tr {
    background: blue;
}
```

That will not work if we have a `<tbody>` tag around the `<tr>` tags.

Is there a way to cover both cases without having to do this:

```
table > tr, table > tbody > tr {
    background: blue;
}
```

We cannot do this also as it will impact grandchildren rows down the tree:

```
table tr {
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no syntax for a "depth range" in CSS, so this way or another you would need to implicitly account for both situations.

You said you want to avoid

```
table > tr, table > tbody > tr {
```

though it's not that long. But the following alternatives would do too:

```
table > tr, tbody > tr {


:is(table, tbody) > tr {


:where(table, tbody) > tr {
```

If the table has a class `my-table`

```
:where(.my-table, .my-table > tbody) > tr {
```

Comment: Merci, thank you.  Although my example was very minimal, we may have much longer row selector like .some-class-A > .some-other-class > table >< tbody > tr, so I was trying to see if we could avoid having to repeat code.  ok, thanks again.

Comment: `:is(table, tbody) > tr` can come at any point in the middle of the selector sequence. I agree that it wouldn't work this way for every possible situation, though as a side note I would avoid long sequences of direct-child selector anyway, as it would break with every change to the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can select any rows you like, by adding a class to them, and creating css styles for this class.

HTML:

```
<tr class="superrow">
  ...
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.superrow { background: blue; }
```